# In vb6, how do I have the open file dialog display files in detail mode?

Tags: vb6, openfiledialog

Need to set the default file display in a vb6 openfiledialog.

Comment: To be more precise, what Flags do I need to set so that the file display is always starting in "detail" mode instead of one of the other file display modes?

Answer (score 3):

You need a hook to send a windows message to the Open/Save dialog and force the details view. Check this post:

http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/hooks/fileopensavedlghooklvview.htm